# Lua - Passing a function with some arguments already filled

Tags: function, lua, arguments

I want to pass a function as an argument, the function to pass takes two arguments. I want the first argument filled, but the second one unfilled. Here is the example:

```
function a(firstarg, secondarg)
    print ("this is the" .. firstarg .. "to the a function and the b function gave it ".. secondarg)
end

function b(givenfunction)
    givenfunction("the second argument.")
```

The desired calls to the function:

```
b(a("first call"))
b(a("second call"))
```

The Desired output of the execution:

```
this is the first call to the a function and the b function gave it the second argument. 
this is the second call to the a function and the b function gave it the second argument.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why not pass 2 values to `b` like `b(a, "first call")` and you define `b` as `function b(givenfunction, arg1) givenfunction(arg1, "the second argument.") end`

Comment: Because b is a function we cannot modify. So we want to pass a function a (that we write ourselves) that can have an argument that is not passed to b directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function inner(firstarg, secondarg)
   print ("this is the" .. firstarg .. "to the a function and the b function gave it ".. secondarg)
end

function a(firstarg)
   return function (secondarg) 
      return inner(firstarg, secondarg)
   end
end

function b(givenfunction)
   givenfunction("the second argument.")
end

b(a("first call"))
b(a("second call"))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks! :)